# Pandas load data frame in to txt file with column value pair

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have loaded csv file into pandas data frame and it looks like below example

```
   c1   c2   c3
0  12   22   66
1  44   78   AB
2  DF   WE   13
```

I want this data frame to be loaded in a .txt file with below format

```
c1="12",c2="22",c3="66"
c1="44",c2="78",c3="AB"
c1="DF",c2="WE",c3="13"
```

Each row should be on new line in the text file.
Please help me out to find out how it can be done in a best optimal way.

Comment: use `df.iterrows()` to iterate over every row and you can access the data for each column on basis of column names and create the lines needed. I am however interested and unsure why you would need to save your data in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to strings, append `"` by [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html), prepend `=` by [`DataFrame.radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html) and also prepend columns names:

```
df = df.astype(str).add('"').radd('="').radd(df.columns.to_series())
#alternative
#df = ('="' + df.astype(str) + '"').radd(df.columns.to_series())
print (df)
        c1       c2       c3
0  c1="12"  c2="22"  c3="66"
1  c1="44"  c2="78"  c3="AB"
2  c1="DF"  c2="WE"  c3="13"
```

And then use [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import csv

df.to_csv('file.txt', header=None, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

---

```
c1="12",c2="22",c3="66"
c1="44",c2="78",c3="AB"
c1="DF",c2="WE",c3="13"
```